# How to apply different functions for different groups and mutate?

Tags: r

```
data <- head(iris)
```

I want to mutate a column "A" with a function
if the value `as.integer(iris$Sepal.Length)` is 1, then the corresponding value in A, should be 1940, 2=1939, 3=1938 etc ... (lower by 1)

we can do like this, but for only for the groups   versicolor and virginica

```
 data %>% mutate(A = 1941 - as.integer(Sepal.Length))
```

but for  setosa, I need

if the value `as.integer(iris$Sepal.Length)` is 1, then the corresponding value in A, should be 1940, 2=1930, 3=1920 etc ... (lower by 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?case_when`, for example:

```
data |>
  mutate(
    A = case_when(
      Species == "setosa" ~ 1950 - 10 * as.integer(Sepal.Length),
      .default = 1941 - as.integer(Sepal.Length)
    )
  )
```

Comment: thanks, what if I want to apply this ~ 1950 - 10 * as.integer(Sepal.Length) for 2 groups ("setosa" and another one)

Comment: Then use `Species %in% c("setosa", "other_species")` instead of `Species == "setosa"`.